# can i add new item using netsuite php toolkit?

Tags: php, netsuite, suitetalk

i'm using netsuite php toolkit 2018_1

i need to add some items from my mysql db to netsuite.
Required internal_id of those items in response.
but not sure how to do that.

i have tried to search lot but seems proper documentation is not available.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend importing the item data using NetSuite's Import/Export tool. Or, if you want to automate the item creation, build a RESTLET using Suitescript that receives the item data from an HTTP Post and pushes the data into NetSuite.